# Minecraft-Forge Mod item has been registered and has been pointed to model for texturing, although in game item is missing texture?

Tags: java, json, macos, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am a primarily JS Dev, and am new to Java so sorry ahead of time for my lack of fluency!

I have created an item "`dirt_ingot`", registered that item (Logged when this was complete to verify), directed it to the model location (Also logged). My JSON file/model functions correctly (Have spent lots of time working with JSONs), when the name of the texture is changed to something different to at least confirm it is making it this far; `"textures": { "layer0" :fm/items/dirt_ingo }` not `dirt_ingot`. It then returned an error in the console that suggested I had no asset in the fm.textures.items package that matched this name which made complete sense as I changed the name to a png that didn't exist. Although when changed back and directed to the correct png I am given a texture error.

Anyone who can help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

**dirt_ingot.json**

```
{
   "parent": "item/generated",
   "textures": {
       "layer0": "fm:items/dirt_ingot"
   }
}
```

**ItemBase.java**

```
package com.ash_haus.firstmod.items;

import com.ash_haus.firstmod.Main;
import com.ash_haus.firstmod.init.ModItems;
import com.ash_haus.firstmod.util.IHasModel;

import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public class ItemBase extends Item implements IHasModel {

    public ItemBase(String name) {

        setUnlocalizedName(name);
        setRegistryName(name);
        setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.MISC);


        ModItems.ITEMS.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerModels() {

        Main.proxy.registerItemRenderer(this, 0, "inventory");
    }

}
```

**CommonProxy.java**

```
package com.ash_haus.firstmod.proxy;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public class CommonProxy {

    public void registerItemRenderer(Item item, int meta, String id) {

    }

}
```

**ClientProxy.java**

```
package com.ash_haus.firstmod.proxy;

import net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader;

public class ClientProxy extends CommonProxy {

    public void registerItemRender(Item item, int meta, String id) {

        ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(item, meta, new ModelResourceLocation(item.getRegistryName(), id));
    }
}
```

**ModItems.java**

```
package com.ash_haus.firstmod.init;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.ash_haus.firstmod.items.ItemBase;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public class ModItems {

    public static final List<Item> ITEMS = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public static final Item DIRT_INGOT = new ItemBase("dirt_ingot");
}
```

**IHasModel.java**

```
package com.ash_haus.firstmod.util;

public interface IHasModel {

    public void registerModels();
}
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.ash_haus.firstmod;

import com.ash_haus.firstmod.proxy.CommonProxy;
import com.ash_haus.firstmod.util.Reference;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.Instance;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy; 
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.NAME, version = Reference.VERSION)
public class Main {

    @Instance
    public static Main instance;

    @SidedProxy(clientSide = Reference.CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS, serverSide = Reference.COMMON_PROXY_CLASS)
    public static CommonProxy proxy;

    @EventHandler
    public static void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event)
    {

    }

    @EventHandler
    public static void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {

    }

    @EventHandler
    public static void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event)
    {

    }
}
```

**Only Error In Console**

```
com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.AuthenticationException: The client has sent too many requests within a certain amount of time
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilAuthenticationService.makeRequest(YggdrasilAuthenticationService.java:79) ~[YggdrasilAuthenticationService.class:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService.fillGameProfile(YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService.java:180) [YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService.class:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService$1.load(YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService.java:60) [YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService$1.class:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService$1.load(YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService.java:57) [YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService$1.class:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3716) [guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2424) [guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2298) [guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2211) [guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4154) [guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4158) [guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:5147) [guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5153) [guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService.fillProfileProperties(YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService.java:170) [YggdrasilMinecraftSessionService.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.getProfileProperties(Minecraft.java:3181) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SkinManager$3.run(SkinManager.java:138) [SkinManager$3.class:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

I just want the texture to render correctly in-game, been fumbling with this for hours! Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Have you tried both .PNG and .png?  Sometimes Windows OS incorrectly displays capital or lower case file extensions.

Comment: I am currently on Mac sadly

Comment: What do the logs say? The logs never lie.

Comment: @Draco18s, I appended the log in my question.